# google.visualization chart - DataTable in google site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-visualization

I'm not understand how to implement chart in Google site.
My goal is to show spreadsheet. I'm choose to use the charts from google.visualization.DataTable with dashboard.

This is my steps:

1) Create new project from apps script project.

2) add file Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myPage').evaluate();
}
```

3) add file myPage.html i take the example from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls?hl=en

I'm add to body "Hello world!" for test.

4) test this HTML code in Google play ground (all work fine)

5) Go to the edit page in my Google site and add this script to page
Insert -> Apps script gadget

6) Save, Reload

As result in my page I see "Hello world!" but table is absent!
What is wrong?
What is the bast way to show table from Google spreadsheet with filers?

Answer (score 1):

See the docs about caja and htmlservice. Those Chart libs are not supported.

Comment: Thanks for all!
I'm not found way to freeze first columns in TableChartBuilder class. How I can do freeze columns?

Answer (score 0):

Zig is right, caja does not support google.visualization libs so far.

What you need is to use the Charts module in GAS UiApp:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/

You can create data table and dashboard. They will look the same as if you have used google.visualization.

Best,

Thierry

Comment: Thanks for all!
I'm not found way to freeze first columns in TableChartBuilder class. How I can do freeze columns?

Comment: I do not think you can using Charts. I do not even think you can with google.visualization, can you ?

Comment: I wrote a complex script for chart table, that selects the column at the request of the user and update the chart. But he is not comfortable and not flexible. There is no possibility to freeze columns. I gave up on it.

Comment: Re freezing columns on TCBuilder: make two tables one to the right of the other. First one has frozen columns. Second one has rest. Wont work if you need vertical scroll